# React i18next trans component with text after link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, i18next

I have a simple trans component that looks like this:

```
    <Trans
      i18nKey="login_screen:terms_of_use"
      components={{
        privacy_policy: (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              void Linking.openURL(
                'https:.....',
              )
            }}
          >
            <Link>{t('privacy_policy')}</Link>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
      }}
    />
```

**And I want to have the following text:**

"Ich stimme die app Dattenschutzbestimmungen zu" where the link is the Dattenschutzbestimmungen.

**Here is my json:**

```
"terms_of_use": "Ich stimme die app <privacy_policy><0><0></privacy_policy> zu",
"privacy_policy": "Datenschutzbestimmungen",
```

With the current solution I get the following text: Ich stimme die app Datenschutzbestimmungen

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the Trans component in this way:

```
<Trans
  i18nKey="login_screen:terms_of_use"
>
  Ich stimme den app
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {
      void Linking.openURL(
        'https:.....',
      )
    }}
  >
    <Link>Dattenschutzbestimmungen</Link>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  zu.
</Trans>
```

with this resources:

```
"terms_of_use": "Ich stimme die app <1><0>Datenschutzbestimmungen</0></1> zu."
```